# Save a toggled star

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, stateful

What's a good way to display a star that the user can click on/off from a webpage similar to the "mark important" star in gmail? Also, similar to the star in stackoverflow (over here to your left!)

I'm using jQuery and rails.

FRONT-side questions:
What's a good and clean way to maintain this in jQuery?
Maybe have a mark important and then add a click listener perhaps?
I'll also need to remember the state and show the star highlighted on and off.

SERVER-side questions:
The other question I have is about routing. When the user clicks on it, it'll POST to the server.

Should it have two routes?

```
POST ./email/mark_important
POST ./email/unmark_important
```

Or should it have or one route?

```
POST ./email/toggle_importance
```

I'm focused on clean code & maintainability. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the standard example of a "too broad" question. Please try some ideas of your own first and ask us again when you have issues.

Comment: Well I do not agree with you. This question seems legit to me. In most applications, primary design tends to be used for a long time, even if it's not the best one, because refactoring takes time and is dangerous without a good test coverage. I'm not saying a bad architecture will stay forever, but that's pretty clever to ask about it before doing mistakes. You may or may not agree to the answers you get, but at least you have ideas to compare to each other. And good architecture needs experience: it's hard to see mistakes or poor design when you do not have it, though better to ask beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the client-side, I'd use a toggle on the css class (for instance "checked" and "unchecked"). After the toggle took place, I'd read the resulting CSS from the element, and call a unique server-side method with an on/off param (a primitive boolean) to save the sate.

This way, you always sends the right value to your server, even if the user clicks a lot of time (and very fast) on the image. The last call will always make things right.